# Unable to import Grade project to Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, gradle, libgdx

I have a libGDX project that I've been developing on a PC and am trying to get it to compile on a Mac.

I've checked out my Gradle project from my repository.  I then select File/Import, select Gradle Project as my import source and browse to the root of my Gradle project.  Then when I click on the Build Model I get the following error:

```
Already created an SDK Loader with different SDK Path

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable.run(GradleRunnable.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Already created an SDK Loader with different SDK Path
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.ExceptionUtil.coreException(ExceptionUtil.java:40)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.ExceptionUtil.coreException(ExceptionUtil.java:51)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.modelmanager.BuildResult.get(BuildResult.java:85)
```

I have a fresh install of Eclipse and earlier I had a dialog box appear asking for my Android SDK root.  Being unfamiliar with Macs and the Android SDK on Macs, I may have entered the wrong path.  Now I would like to edit this path, but I can find no way to do so and I have no idea where Eclipse has cached it on my machine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as the location of the option for SDK path, you're going to want to go to Window -> Preferences, select the Android section on the left, and the SDK location can be set at the top.  If you change that around and it doesn't fix the other problem, let us know.  I get the feeling that's not it, though.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't help.  It looks like I'm already pointing to my Android install which is /Users/me/bin/android-sdk-macosx.  I'm getting the below error message when eclipse starts up.

Comment: [2015-08-23 22:44:35 - Android SDK] Error when loading the SDK:

Error: Error parsing /Users/me/bin/android-sdk-macosx/system-images/android-22/android-wear/armeabi-v7a/devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
Error: Error parsing /Users/me/bin/android-sdk-macosx/system-images/android-22/android-wear/x86/devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.

Comment: Odd.  I've been getting that error myself lately, but it doesn't affect anything for me.  I usually don't even have to refresh the projects.